# Primary Key in three tables

Tags: sql

Just curious if I can have the same primary key in 3 different tables? I am going to create an Employee, FullTime and PartTime tables. I would like to make an EmployeeID the primary key for all 3. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why create 3 different tables?  Create 1 and have a employee Type that indicates if they are full/part time?  Seems to me you'd be capturing the same data.  or an employeeTypes table if there are specific attributes about full/part time you need to capture..

Answer (score 3):

You can have the primary key `EmployeeId` in a table called `Employees`.  This would have common information, such as date of hire and so on.

Then, each of your subtables can have an `EmployeeId` that is both a primary key in the table *and* a foreign key reference to `Employees.EmployeeId`.  This is one way to implement a one-of relationship using relational tables.

Unfortunately, unless you use triggers, this mechanism doesn't prevent one employee from being in the two other tables, but that is not part of your question.

Comment: What would I make as the primary key for Employees then?

Comment: that make more sense to me now. I am new to sql and just wasnt sure how to implement those keys. Thanks!

Comment: No need for triggers, just had the emp type to each table and its key (pk/fk)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your design is wrong.

The *entity* is the employee

An *attribute* of an employee is their [current^] employment status.

Therefore, in its simplest form, you need a single employee table, with a column that indicates their status.

To improve this further, the employee status column should have a foreign key relationship with another table that stores the possible employee statuses.

^ *current status is a 1:1 relationship. If you wanted the history of changes, this is a 1:M and needs modelling differently.*